# How JIT in R compares to JIT in Julia and JIT in Python?

Tags: python, r, julia, jit

As I understood JIT in both R and Julia happens automatically, while in Python a separate package and a manual decoration of the functions to JIT-compile is required.

Adide of this, how the usage of JIT in there three language differs? Are there characteristics of the language that make the compiler's job harder or less efficient in some language compared to others?

Comment: While I think this is a very interesting question, I think (esp in light of the quick votes to close) it is off-topic for StackOverflow. It might be more appropriate in https://langdev.stackexchange.com (on-topic includes *"Compiler design and implementation, such as parsing, optimization, and code generation"*) or _maybe_ https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com (though *"Explaining, writing or debugging code"* is off-topic).

Comment: @Antonello, if you re-ask the question on langdev.stackexchange.com, I'll be happy to write an answer to the question.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski: https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/how-jit-in-r-compares-to-jit-in-julia-and-jit-in-python